# Replace string with another string shell script

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file in the format:

`"data","data","data",data"`.

Now if data has a `"` in it, then my parser cannot parse the file. So I want to use sed to replace `"` with `"""` but not where it sees `","` as that is essentially the delimiter.

I can't figure out what the sed parameters should be.

Comment: What if the data contain `","`?

Comment: @choroba there is nothing I can do about that case. It is not a regular language, but a CFG (think I got my terminology correct there)

Comment: Why not three steps: first change "," to something like ~. Then change " to """. Then change ~ back to "," . (if needed, use something instead of ~ that won't appear in your data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you can also do this in `sed` but it is much easier for me in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/([^,])\"/$1xxx/g; s/xxx,/\",/g; s/xxx/\"\"\"/g' data.txt
```

EXPLANATION:

- `perl -pe` : execute the script given on the command line on each line of the input file
- `s/([^,])\"/$1xxx/g;` : substitute every occurrence of `"` preceded by any non-comma character with a random string `xxx`. This assumes that your data will never contain `xxx`.
- `s/xxx,/\",/g;` : substitute those `xxx` that are followed by a comma back to `",`.
- `s/xxx/\\\"/g` : replace the rest of the `xxx` with escaped quotes `\"`, these will be the `"` that were in your data.

EXAMPLE:

```
$ cat test.txt
"data","da"t"a","data","data","foo "bar" foo", "data"

$ perl -pe 's/([^,])\"/$1xxx/g; s/xxx,/\",/g; s/xxx//g' test.txt 
"data","data","data","data","foo bar foo","data
```

Comment: I don't want to remove them, just escape them!

Comment: @Ben, OK, modified the answer to escape instead of remove.

Comment: thanks, I actually got the picture from the excellent explanation you gave...just didn't want to accept the answer until it answered the question...I hate to nit-pick, but the escape is a double double quote not a backslash as per the op

Comment: You're not nitpicking @Ben, I should learn to read questions. Thanks for pointing it out, it should work now.